# How two show two columns total in third one using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a JSON data by which I am rendering a table, inside table I have created two input fields one for `Quantity` and other for `Total`, I have one field named as `selling price` so what I am trying to do is for each row `quantity * selling price = Total` that total should be in total column of table, And also I want to show the cumulative total in a input field,

- Example row one = quantity (1) * selling price (5) = total (5)
- Example row one = quantity (3) * selling price (4) = total (12)

Now In above input I want to show `17`

The cumulative Total, I tried using keyup but it is not working.

**My total code**

```js
let data = [{
    "Item Name": "tea",
    "Selling Price": "150.0000",
    "Qty": "0",
    "Total": 0
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "ice cream",
    "Selling Price": "130.0000",
    "Qty": "0",
    "Total": 0
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "coffie",
    "Selling Price": "130.0000",
    "Qty": "0",
    "Total": 0
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "churma",
    "Selling Price": "100.0000",
    "Qty": "0",
    "Total": 0
  }
]



var itemsQuantiry1 = [];
var totalQty1 = []

function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {

      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];

      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        tabCell.classList.add('widthTable')
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);

        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Selling Price'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Selling_Price');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }



      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Qty'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {

        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity_field");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");

        quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "tel");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Total'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {

        var totalField = document.createElement("input");
        totalField.style.border = "none";
        totalField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        totalField.setAttribute("name", "total");
        totalField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        totalField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        totalField.setAttribute("index", i);
        totalField.setAttribute("type", "tel");
        totalField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        totalField.classList.add("total");
        totalField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(totalField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("indentTable");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");


}
addTableDraft(data)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>

  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="cumTotal" placeholder="Cum Total">
  <table id=indentTable></table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Too much work. Why not use jQuery when you have it?
`const $table = $("<table/>"), $thead = $("<thead/>"), $thr = $("<tr/>");
Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]).forEach(key => thr.append(\`<th class="text-center head">${key}</th>\`); $thead.append($thr); $table.append($thead)`

Comment: i am using jquery only, i have made my table as per need, here i have uploaded only simplified version, else i have so manythings in my table, for that i am rendering my table like above

Comment: If your real table is different from this you published in the post, there is a high probability that the solution in my answer will not work! In order to be able to make a more universal version, I will need to change the code you have made so far ... but this can confuse you. So I think it's best to show the real table.

Comment: @54ka table is same it is just that data is much more and some other event listers are there, I am checking with your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a value is entered in the "Qty" field and press "Enter" or go to the next field. The function takes the required values and returns the calculated result to "Total".

Then the function `cumTotalFunc()` collects the values from total and calculates them for "Cum Total"

I hope I've been helpful

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style>

    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <input type="text" id="cumTotal" placeholder="Cum Total">
    <table id=indentTable></table>

    <script>
        let data = [{
            "Item Name": "tea",
            "Selling Price": "150.0000",
            "Qty": "0",
            "Total": 0
        },
        {
            "Item Name": "ice cream",
            "Selling Price": "130.0000",
            "Qty": "0",
            "Total": 0
        },
        {
            "Item Name": "coffie",
            "Selling Price": "130.0000",
            "Qty": "0",
            "Total": 0
        },
        {
            "Item Name": "churma",
            "Selling Price": "100.0000",
            "Qty": "0",
            "Total": 0
        }
        ]



        var itemsQuantiry1 = [];
        var totalQty1 = []

        function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
            var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
            var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
            var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
            col = col.concat(num);
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                var th = document.createElement("th");
                th.innerHTML = col[i];
                tr.appendChild(th);
                tr.classList.add("text-center");
                tr.classList.add("head")
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
                tr = table.insertRow(-1);
                tr.classList.add("item-row");
                for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {

                    let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                    hiddenField.style.display = "none";
                    var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];

                    if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
                        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
                        tabCell.classList.add('widthTable')
                        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
                        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);

                        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
                    }
                    if (tableDataDraft[i]['Selling Price'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
                        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
                        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Selling_Price');
                        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
                        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
                    }



                    if (tableDataDraft[i]['Qty'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {

                        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
                        quantityField.style.border = "none";
                        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
                        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity_field");
                        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");

                        quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
                        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
                        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "tel");
                        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
                        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
                        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
                        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
                    }
                    if (tableDataDraft[i]['Total'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {

                        var totalField = document.createElement("input");
                        totalField.style.border = "none";
                        totalField.style["text-align"] = "right";
                        totalField.setAttribute("name", "total");
                        totalField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
                        totalField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
                        totalField.setAttribute("index", i);
                        totalField.setAttribute("type", "tel");
                        totalField.setAttribute("required", "required");
                        totalField.classList.add("total");
                        totalField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
                        tabCell.appendChild(totalField);
                    }

                    if (j > 1)
                        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
                }
            }
            var divContainer = document.getElementById("indentTable");
            divContainer.innerHTML = "";
            divContainer.appendChild(table);
            table.classList.add("table");
            table.classList.add("table-striped");
            table.classList.add("table-bordered");
            table.classList.add("table-hover");

            calculateTotal();

        }
        addTableDraft(data);

        function calculateTotal() {

            var list = document.getElementsByClassName('dataReset');
            for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                list[i].addEventListener("change", function () {

                    var y = this.parentElement;
                    var z = y.parentElement;

                    var w = z.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerText;
                    var t = z.getElementsByClassName('total')[0];

                    var res = w * this.value;

                    t.setAttribute('value', res);

                    cumTotalFunc();
                });
            }
        }


        function cumTotalFunc() {
            var ct = document.getElementById('cumTotal');
            var t = document.getElementsByClassName('total');
            var res = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
                res += +t[i].value;
            }

            ct.setAttribute('value', res);
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

*I fixed bug in my code: If the value returns to 0 now work*

---

If in your code you add an attribute `data-price` with price value on element with name `name="Quantity_field"`

You can replace this line:

```
var w = z.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerText;
```

with this

```
var w = this.getAttribute('data-price');
```

That would be a better solution!

Comment: Hey I got one issue in your code or I don't know why it is not working as expected, I have one clear button on click of which I am clearing quantity total and cumTotal, but after that I am putting some value in quantity then it is not doing the calculation   `$("#clear").click(function() {
  $(".total").val(0)
  $(".dataReset").val(0)
  $("#cumTotal").val(0)
})`    

Please do check why this is happening

Comment: Try this code: $("#clear").click(function () {
    $(".total").removeAttr('value');
    $(".dataReset").val(0);
    $(".dataReset").removeAttr('value');
    $("#cumTotal").removeAttr('value');
});